# Установка модулей в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, установка

Не получается установить библиотеки Python в PyCharm.
Использую Python 3.10.6, windows 10 x64.
Для примера - попробую установить requests через терминал PyCharm в свое виртуальное окружение.
Такая ошибка:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\alexandrovn\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1> pip install requests
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016A2A3D2530>, 'Connection to py
pi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016A2A3D0250>, 'Connection to py
pi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016A2A3D0D90>, 'Connection to py
pi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016A2A3D2B00>, 'Connection to py
pi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016A2A445300>, 'Connection to py
pi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests
```

Также, я посмотрел несколько видео и попытался установить через Settings - Python Interpreter - Нажимаю на "+", над надписью package и в окне Available Packages идет обновление и появляется сообщение:

Reload List of Packages
Error updating package list: Connect timed out

[image: Описание]

Также я пробовал установить из вкладки View - Tool Windows - Python Packages(хотя там список библиотек очень маленький).
Выбираю requests и результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, я уже не понимаю, в чем проблема, обрыл все источники, которые находил.
Ранее, я устанавливал Anaconda и делал ее основным Интерпретатором, в ней были некие библиотеки, в списке - Available Packages и я сразу их импортировал в проекты, но ни одну стороннюю библиотеку я не могу установить.

Comment: может вам нужно настроить proxy ?

Comment: Спасибо за хорошую идею, я сейчас попробовал настроить Proxy в PyCharm и это не помогло. Но, я понял, что я с корпоративного ПК и у нас есть блокировки от Компании, думаю надо копать в эту сторону, возможно пообщаться с админами сети.